# Why isn't monit firing off git properly?

Tags: git, monit

I have a monit service running.
It checks to see if a file changed, then it fires off a script to make sure that file gets put into git:

```
check file ncc_db with path /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/production.sqlite3
      if changed checksum then exec "/home/ootbdv/ncc_db/autocommit.sh"
```

I know that I've setup monit correctly because the log file shows this.

```
[PDT Jun  3 01:04:14] info     : 'ncc_db' checksum has not changed
[PDT Jun  3 01:10:14] error    : 'ncc_db' checksum was changed for /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/production.sqlite3
[PDT Jun  3 01:10:14] info     : 'ncc_db' exec: /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/autocommit.sh
[PDT Jun  3 01:12:14] error    : 'ncc_db' checksum was changed for /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/production.sqlite3
[PDT Jun  3 01:12:14] info     : 'ncc_db' exec: /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/autocommit.sh
[PDT Jun  3 01:14:14] info     : 'ncc_db' checksum has not changed
```

So I know that monit is working.
I also know the script is working because, as root, when I type in `/home/ootbdv/ncc_db/autocommit.sh` the script works as expected, it jumps into the directory and fires off the git command.

#### The script:

```
#/bin/bash

cd /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/
git commit -a -m 'monit:autocommit'
```

> Am I doing something wrong such that monit isn't working as expected?

Comment: Is this is the right content (missing parenthesis) `git commit -a -m 'monit:autocommit`

Comment: Corrected that typo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the header in the script was incorrect; it should have read `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#/bin/bash`.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is correct but you did not push the added files back to the remote repository.

You added the file to your **local repository** and now you have to push it to the remote repository

### The script:

```
#/bin/bash

cd /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/
git commit -a -m 'monit:autocommit'
git push <origin_name> <branch_name>
```

Comment: I don't need to push it to a remote repository. The local repository is fine. My workaround was just to create this common directly in the monit config file: `check file ncc_db with path /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/production.sqlite3
      if changed checksum then exec "/bin/bash -c 'cd /home/ootbdv/ncc_db/;git commit -a -m monit:auto commit'"`